# Wordpress rest API 403 Forbidden you don't have permission to access this resource error

Tags: ajax, wordpress, rest

I defined, custom routes for my WordPress app.
When I sent an Ajax GET request to the defined routes in my WordPress rest API, they worked fine, But when I sent a POST request, I would get the following error:

> 403 Forbidden you dont have permission to access this resource error

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was sending requests to the wrong route :).
you have to send a request to your route with this format:
your domain / **wp-json** / namespace / route

I forgot to put wp-json, so my route was totally wrong. and WordPress would yell at me, you don't have permission to access this resource.
I Thank myself :D.